# Trying to trigger an url from azure functions using python, errored saying "without a $return binding returned a non-None value"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, azure

Below is the code,

```
import logging
import json 
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://example.com:5000/processing")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    }
```

Error: Result: Failure Exception: RuntimeError: function 'abc' without a $return binding returned a non-None value Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 341, in _handle__invocation_request f'function {fi.name!r} without a $return binding '.  The same code works in lambda.. Please help me in debugging in azure functions.

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "sourcemetadata/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `funtion.json` file?

Comment: @JimXu Added function.json above

Comment: @JimXu If i have folder structure inside container .. Container name : abc Folder name : example... How can i define path in function.json? ---- "path": "abc/example/{name}.csv",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Azure function, if you use `return` in the function app code, it means that you want to use output binding. But you do not define it in function.json. Please define it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-return-value?tabs=csharp) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#outputs)

For example

I use process blob with blob trigger and send message to azure queue with queue output binding

1. function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "test/{name}.csv",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "queue",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Code

```
async def main(myblob: func.InputStream) :
    
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n")
    return "OK"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim Xu for clarifying how "return" works with azure functions. I have configured the same and it works well.

Comment: If i have folder structure inside container .. Container name : abc  Folder name : example... How can i define path in function.json?  ----  "path": "abc/example/{name}.csv",

Comment: Yes you can define path like that